# Why would vagrant generates some junk files when I run a "vagrant ssh -c COMMAND" script by using npm run?

Tags: npm, vagrant, vagrantfile

Here is my `package.json` and `Vagrantfile`:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "vagrant-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "hello": "vagrant ssh -c 'echo 1'"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

**Vagrantfile**

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "bento/centos-7.1"
end
```

When I `npm run hello`, vagrant will generates some junk file looks like this:

[image]

How could I fix this issue?